# OpenLayers origin at top left of map

Tags: coordinate-system, javascript, openlayers

I have an OpenLayers map which uses an ImageLayer as the base layer and I want to create a custom projection so that (0, 0) is at the top left of the image rather than the bottom left.

I tried setting the projection's axisOrientation to 'esu' but that did not change the axis in any way. I tried creating my own proj4 projection, but the origin is still appearing at the bottom left of the image.

```
  proj4.defs(
            'newproj',
            '+proj=somerc +axis=esu +units=m +no_defs'
  );
  register(proj4);
  this.proj = get('newproj');
  this.proj.setExtent(this.getImageExtent());

  var view_options = {
            projection: this.proj,
            center: getCenter(this.getImageExtent()),
            zoom: 2,
            extent: this.getImageExtent(),
  };
  this.view = new View(view_options);

  this.map = new Map({
            target: 'map',
            view: this.view,
  });
```